# How to convert Hex array's single element to int

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I have a hex value stored in a two byte array :

**unsigned char hex[2] = {0x84, 0xA5};**

How can I convert only first element of an array to a decimal value, i.e **hex[0] to int** ?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what you need: you have an array of chars. don't be bothered by the fact that you initialized them with hex format - they are saved in memory as bits regardless. if you want to print them in hex format or int format - please state so. If you want help converting them to int (as opposed to char) please say so.

Comment: The array does not contain "a hex value", it contains a *value*, irrespective of your notation. There is nothing there to 'convert'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it:

```
int i = hex[0];
```

Comment: Thanks alk. Sometimes we forgot very basics also :-)

Comment: @SumitSharma: You are welcome. If this answers your question, please mark it as such by checking its exclamation mark.

Comment: @SumitSharma: Make sure `hex` is declared as `unsigned` `char`.

Comment: Thanks this **unsigned char ** made a lot change, else i was getting -ve values for values higher than 128 decimal value.